# Proving double inequality by cases

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-explanation

I am puzzled by an exercise in Vellemen's How To Prove It, here is the exercise:

Prove that for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a| \le b$ iff $-b \le a \le b $.

There is actually no official solution for this exercise, but one solution I found online (recommended by Peter Smith from Cambridge, so I assume much of it is correct) suggests a proof by case approach. For the left to right direction, he considers case 1: $a\ge0$ and case 2: $a\lt0$, so that we can assume $|a|=a$ or $|a|=-a$ for the respective cases.

How he completed each case is pretty easy, what I don't understand is how he used the conclusion from each case to reach the conclusion. The conclusion for case 1 and 2, are $a\le b$ and $-b \le a$ respectively.

Then he concluded, 'So either $a\le b$ or $-b \le a$, therefore $-b \le a \le b $.'

I don't understand how is this valid, i.e. how you can join the conclusion from the two cases together with a disjunction to form the conclusion? Because to me, double inequality should be a conjunction, i.e. b is greater or equal to a, AND a is greater or equal to -b.

Furthermore, shouldn't he have concluded $-b \le a \le b $ from EACH case, and then say that since the cases exhaust all logical possibilities, thus the conclusion is true? How come he can get away with only proving one side of the double inequality with each case?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The two cases are $a\ge 0$ and $a< 0$ without the absolute value. By definition of absolute value we cannot have $|a| < 0$ !

Comment: Surely you have the cases wrong: $|a|\le 0$ means $a=0$. Probably the cases are $a\ge 0, a < 0$.

Comment: @BrianO: thanks ! fixed..

Comment: Thank you! The mistakes are corrected, should be ok now

Comment: Yep it's fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $|a|\le b \Rightarrow b\ge 0$ since $|a| \ge 0$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Now from:
$$
\left( a \ge 0 \Rightarrow |a|=a\right) \land \left( a < 0 \Rightarrow |a|=-a\right)
$$
we have:

$$
\left( |a| \le b \right) \iff \left[ \left( a \ge 0\right) \land \left( a \le b\right) \right] \lor \ \left[ \left( a < 0\right) \land \left( -a \le b\right) \right]
$$
and, since $\left( -a \le b\right) \iff \left(-b \le a\right)$ we have:

$$
\left( |a| \le b \right) \iff \left[ \left( a \ge 0\right) \land \left( a \le b\right) \right] \lor \ \left[ \left( a < 0\right) \land \left( -b \le a\right) \right]
$$
Now, since $b \ge 0$ we have $-b \le b$ so $-b\le a \le b$

Comment: I have a few things which I don't understand:
1. Is [(a≥0)∧(a≤b)]∨ [(a<0)∧(−a≤b)] the same as −b≤a≤b? But why isn't it [(a≥0)∧(a≤b)]∧ [(a<0)∧(−a≤b)] instead? Disjunction doesn't seem to make sense to me.
2. Is (−a≤b)⟺(−b≤a) because you can get −b≤a from multiplying -1 with −a≤b?
3. 'since b≥0 we have −b≤b', I get where is b≥0 coming from, but how does −b≤b come from b≥0? (And it seems to be counter-intuitive that -b can be equal to b?)

Comment: I start from 3). This is a consequence of the definition of order in $\mathbb{R}$. For two real numbers we have $b\ge c \iff b-c \ge 0$, so, for $b\ge 0$ we have $b-(-b)=b+b=2b\ge 0$ and $b \ge -b$.

Comment: For 2). Yes,we can prove that if we multiply the two sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality change the order.

Comment: For 1) Using distributivity of the logical connectives the expression $\left[ \left( a \ge 0\right) \land \left( a \le b\right) \right] \lor \ \left[ \left( a < 0\right) \land \left( -b \le a\right) \right]$  is equivalent to $(a \ge 0) \lor (a<0) ] \land [(-b \le a) \land (a \le b)]$ that is $-b\le a \le b \; \forall a$. If you substitute the  middle $\lor$ with  an $\land$ you find $(a\ge 0) \land (a<0)$ that cannot be verified in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Peter Smith's proof, but the cases play out as follows:

1) ($0 \le a$) Then $|a|\le b$ *iff* $-b\le a \le b$ because $-b\le 0$ and $a = |a|$.

2) ($a < 0$) Then $|a| = -a$. By 1), $|-a|\le b$ *iff* $-b \le -a \le b$. Because $x\le y$ iff $-y\le -x$, and $|a| = |-a|$, we get $|a|\le b$ *iff* $-b \le -a = |a| \le --b = b$.

Comment: For case 1, would you mind explaining why is -b less than or equal to 0 please? Shouldn't it just be less than, as -b is negative? For my own proof, this is actually I got stuck: I think I can prove -b is less than a, but I can't prove that -b is equal to a.

Comment: For case 2, after the supposition of a < 0, do you mean 'By 1), -a ≤ b iff -b ≤ a ≤ b', and '|a|= -a'? Otherwise I don't understand how you derived what you wrote...?

Comment: For case 1: $0\le b$ because $0 \le a = |a|$, so both $|a|\le b$ and $-b \le a\le b$ imply that, so $-b \le 0$. // Case 2, again: by 1), $|a| = |-a|\le b\iff -b\le -a \le b$, so taking negatives, $\iff -b \le --a = a \le --b = b$.

Comment: For case 1: I understand 0≤b, it comes naturally from 0≤a=|a| and |a|≤b. But I don't understand why does −b≤0. It seems to me that it comes from |a|≤b and −b≤a≤b. But the latter is the conclusion we seek, not a given; how could we use the conclusion to derive something?

Comment: For case 2: I still don't understand where is |a|=|−a| coming from; if you meant |a|=−a (because a<0) that would have made sense to me. Also, I am also not sure where is  the '⟺−b≤−a≤b' coming from. Isn't that the conclusion we are supposed to derive, instead of an assumption we can use?

Comment: Re 1: if $0\le b$ then $-b \le 0 = -0$.

Comment: Re 2: Please consult the definition of absolute value. And re the 2nd thing you're not sure about, I said "By 1), ..." i.e. the case we already proved.